# Is it possible to change run id in mlflow?

Tags: python, mlflow

When starting mlflow tracking, it looks like

```
with mlflow.start_run():
```

and there's an options 'run_id=' in start_run()
but as far as I know that's just to specify the run , not creating or changing run_id.
Is there any way to create run_id when calling start_run() or after the start_run()?

Answer (score 0):

The `run_id` is an opaque identifier
that MLflow produces
and that you must preserve.
The [docs](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html#mlflow.start_run) are pretty specific
about the ID being for specifying resumption
of a previous run, rather than for attempting
to produce some interesting spelling of a *new* ID
on a new run.

Perhaps you have a use case for non-opaque IDs.
The current MLflow 2.0 release does not address it.
Feel free to implement a new feature PR,
and submit it to upstream.

When you send multiple attributes into a new .start_run()
you probably want to remember them,
so you can associate them with the ID that comes back.

Comment: How could you write the data created by your program in the same folder as MLFlow without store artefact (e.g. logs.), you need its run_id. However you can't modify the run_id so you end up with this imposed run_id.

You don't want to move the folder created by MLFLow neither inside a custom created directory neither.

So that's why